# Encountered "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent'. " on real device, but not on emulator

Tags: appium, appium-android

I think the issue `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent'.`  has been addressed in several posts, but my circumstances are different. I am testing a 3rd party mobile app (so adding the android:exported="true" is out of the question), using Appium v1.15.1.

**1st Scenario :**
Connect to a real device (mobile and tablet). Using Appium, I cannot start session to  replicate the app in order to check for the element's location. Appium logs shows this issue `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent`

**2nd Scenario :**
COnnect to emulator (LDPLayer4). Using Appium I can start session and the mobile app is replicated in Appium. I can start to check the elements' locator.

I am just wondering what causes the behaviour in scenario 1.